# I need to split every 3 div and append them to a div

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a generic list

```
<div id="banner">
     <div class="oneByOne_item top_offers">
          <div class="top_offer_wrap">item1</div>
          <div class="top_offer_wrap">item2</div>
          <div class="top_offer_wrap">item3</div>
          <div class="top_offer_wrap">item4</div>   
          <div class="top_offer_wrap">item5</div>   
          <div class="top_offer_wrap">item6</div>       
     </div>
</div>
```

But what I want to do is

```
<div id="banner">
     <div class="oneByOne_item top_offers">
          <div class="top_offer_wrap">item1</div>
          <div class="top_offer_wrap">item2</div>
          <div class="top_offer_wrap">item3</div>
     </div>
     <div class="oneByOne_item top_offers">
          <div class="top_offer_wrap">item4</div>   
          <div class="top_offer_wrap">item5</div>   
          <div class="top_offer_wrap">item6</div>       
     </div>
</div>
```

I could use any advice as to the best way to deal with this situation.

Comment: I doubt there is a "best" way. Get an array of nodes, divide the array into groups of three, create a new parent element for each of the groups and append all the nodes accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `<div class="oneByOne_item top_offers">` in your HTML you can use the jQuery functions [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) and [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) to add it again like so:

```
var div = $("#banner > div");
for(var i = 0; i < div.length; i+=3) {
  div.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='oneByOne_item top_offers'></div>");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: jQuery isn't listed as a tag, and therefore answers should be provided in 'regular'/'pure' javascript. (hover over the tag)

Comment: I see, my mistake. Javascript is often used in combination with jQuery so I figured. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure javascript

```
function separate() {
    var container = document.getElementById('banner');
    var divElems = container.querySelectorAll(".top_offer_wrap");
    var count = 0;
    var newDiv = null;
    for (var i = 3; i < divElems.length ; i++) {
        if(count == 0) {
            newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.className = 'oneByOne_item top_offers';
            container.appendChild(newDiv);
        }

        var tempDiv = divElems[i];
        tempDiv.parentNode.removeChild(tempDiv);

        newDiv.appendChild(tempDiv);
        count ++;

        if(count == 3) {
            count = 0;
        }

    }

}
```

Not tested though :)

Comment: Change the for loop as `for (var i = 3; i < divElems.length ; i++)`

Comment: Edited the answer with the above comment

Answer (score 0):

It's not intelligent to do this with javascript. You should do this on the server-side.

If you really want to do it in javascript, you can use the following script:

```
var banner = document.getElementById('banner');

var children = banner.getElementsByClassName('oneByOne_item')[0].getElementsByTagName('div');

var output = "";

for( var i = 0; i < children.length; i += 3 ) {
    var div = "<div class=\"oneByOne_item top_offers\">";
    div += children[i].outerHTML;
    if( i + 1 < children.length ) {
        div += children[i+1].outerHTML;
    }
    if( i + 2 < children.length ) {
        div += children[i+2].outerHTML;
    }
    div += "</div>";

    output += div;
}

banner.innerHTML = output;
```

The code should be self-explenatory. I use [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById), [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.getElementsByClassName) and [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName) to select the right element(s) to do the operations on.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P95bQ/

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery.

like this (already test):

```
var len = $('.top_offer_wrap').length,
    length = len % 3 ? (len / 3) + 1 : len / 3,
    html = '';

for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
   html += '<div class="oneByOne_item top_offers">';
   for(var j = 1; j < 4 && i * 3 + j <= len; j++){
    html += ' <div class="top_offer_wrap">item' + (i * 3 + j)+'</div>';
   }
   html += '<div>';
}

$('#banner').html(html);
```

Comment: Your solution has a typo. As for jQuery; if jQuery isn't listed in the question or in the tags, an answer in pure javascript should be provided. See JrnDel's answer too.